# Laravel - Error with objects and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I'm working on a `Laravel` application that needs to export `.xls` reports, and for this I'm using the [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) library. When I'm in the development environment, the flow happens normally. The problem happens in the production environment, when we try export the report, the system says I'm working with an `object`, not an `array`. But when I change the declaration to `object`, it accuses it is actually an `array`. I'm not understanding anything else. Has anyone ever had this? What is the solution?

This code is where the error occurs:

```
$excel->sheet("Sheet1", function ($sheet) use ($followupData) {
  //some code above
  $city = $paciente['demographic']['city'];
  $sheet->cell('AK8', ExportCenter::TranslateOption($city->joinville));
  //some code below
)->export('xls');
```

The function `TranslateOption()` :

```
private static function TranslateOption($value)
{
     $options = new \App\Option();
     $op = $options->where('value', $value)->first();
     return ExportCenter::TratamentoBranco($op['label']);
}
```

Comment: provide the code and the exact error

Comment: I think @connormcwood is trying to say that something like a stack trace or error log output would be very beneficial in helping us understand what the issue is!

Comment: One more thing, @Fredson P. R. – it appears that you've left a placeholder in your question: [link] library. I'm sure that referencing the library more clearly would help us would-be debuggers to understand what's going on.

Comment: @CameronHurd I fixed the link

Comment: @connormcwood Sure.

Comment: The code is a start, but I'd like to see the stack trace, too!

Comment: @CameronHurd
FatalThrowableError
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

in ExportCenter.php (line 339)
at ExportCenter::App\Export\{closure}(object(LaravelExcelWorksheet))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(LaravelExcelWorksheet))
in LaravelExcelWriter.php (line 239)
at LaravelExcelWriter->sheet('Sheet1', object(Closure))
in ExportCenter.php (line 401)

Comment: Can you put the full stack trace in your question? I'd like to see which of your controllers/services it traces back to. Also - maybe it's worth naming the files that your code excerpts are from, above!

Comment: Also - can you confirm 100% that your dev & production environments have parity?

Comment: @CameronHurd I imported the production database into my dev environment. Now the same error is happening here.

Comment: Interesting! I wonder if there's a serialized object in the db where there shouldn't be. Can you post the full stack trace, and if you're able, a `var_dump` of the variable that's not typed the way `Laravel-Excel` expects?